# Error calling controller-action from JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this call in my master page:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<%= Url.Action("CreateTermSheet", "Indications") %>",
                    data: GetJSONForID(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('Success!');
                    }
                });
```

But when I go to load the page it doesn't render and I get this compilation error:

CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context

What's wrong? I do this other places in my app completely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means here that your views did not reference `System.Web.Mvc`. It should be automatically added by Visual Studio. Check the reference in your **Views** Web.config (Project Directory/Views/Web.config) in `<system.web>/<pages>`

```
<controls>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
</controls>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your master page is an MVC master page i.e. it inherits from [System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.aspx) and not from [System.Web.UI.MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

Then you will have the [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewmasterpage.url.aspx) property inside and its respective [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758.aspx) method.